# There is a way to set the "top toolbar" option in gutenberg by default?

Tags: drupal-8, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm using Gutenberg in Drupal 8, and I am trying to set "Top toolbar" option checked by default.

[image: Top toolbar option]

I'm referring to the format toolbar. Any programmatica solutions?

Comment: I have tried wp.data.dispatch( 'core/block-editor' ).updateSettings( {hasFixedToolbar: true} ); but it doesn't work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the way:

```
const isfixedToolbar = wp.data.select( 'core/edit-post' ).isFeatureActive( 'fixedToolbar' );

if ( !isfixedToolbar ) {
    wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post' ).toggleFeature( 'fixedToolbar' );
}
```

Here: https://gutenbergtimes.com/block-editor-updates-for-the-wordpress-5-4-release/

And here: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/15264

Comment: Thanks for this great find. It saved me hours of trial and error!

Answer (score 1):

To fix the top tool-bar in Gutenberg for WordPress by default put the following code in your functions.php file

```
function jba_enable_editor_fixedToolbar_by_default() {
    $script = "window.onload = function() { const isfixedToolbar = wp.data.select( 'core/edit-post' ).isFeatureActive( 'fixedToolbar' ); if ( !isfixedToolbar ) { wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post' ).toggleFeature( 'fixedToolbar' ); } }";
    wp_add_inline_script( 'wp-blocks', $script );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'jba_enable_editor_fixedToolbar_by_default' );
```

Comment: Can't speak for Drupal, but this works perfectly in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

@ecdani's answer didn't work for me, although the answer was in one of the links on the page they linked to.
https://jeanbaptisteaudras.com/en/2020/03/disable-block-editor-default-fullscreen-mode-in-wordpress-5-4/

Paste this in your functions.php file:

```
function jba_disable_editor_fullscreen_by_default() {
    $script = "window.onload = function() { const isFullscreenMode = wp.data.select( 'core/edit-post' ).isFeatureActive( 'fullscreenMode' ); if ( isFullscreenMode ) { wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post' ).toggleFeature( 'fullscreenMode' ); } }";
    wp_add_inline_script( 'wp-blocks', $script );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'jba_disable_editor_fullscreen_by_default' );
```